# Merging Data Set hierarchies From a List

Tags: c#, list, tree, hierarchy

I made an attempt to be as through as possible.

I have a class that has a property that can in fact hold it self. Let's call the class `ItemSet`. Item set has a method called *Add* that allows one set to be added to the set that the `Add()` is being called on.

**ItemSet**

```
    public class ItemSet
    {
        public string Name{get; set;}
        public List<ItemSet> ItemSets {get; set;}

        public void Add(ItemSet) 
        {
                ItemSets.Add(ItemSet); //Not exactly how is but this example should work.
        }
   }
```

So... let's say I have a list of these sets. `List<ItemSet> setList`;
This list represents every possible combination of hierarchies available.

For conversation, let's say these represent a State, County, City and Hierarchy. I am using JSON like notation below to illustrate what I'm working with.

```
setList[0] = 
{
     Name:Texas,
     ItemSet : 
     {
         Name: Tarrant,
         ItemSet : 
         { 
              Name: Fort Worth
              ....
         }
     }
}
setList[1] = 
{
     Name:Texas,
     ItemSet : 
     {
         Name: Tarrant,
         ItemSet : 
         { 
              Name: Arlington
              ....
         }
     }
}
setList[2] = 
{
     Name:Texas,
     ItemSet : 
     {
         Name: Dallas,
         ItemSet : 
         { 
              Name: Dallas
              ....
         }
     }
}
setList[3] = 
{
     Name:Texas,
     ItemSet : 
     {
         Name: Dallas,
         ItemSet : 
         { 
              Name: Plano
              ....
         }
     }
}
setList[4] = 
{
     Name:Washington,
     ItemSet : 
     {
         Name: King,
         ItemSet : 
         { 
              Name: Seatle
              ....
         }
     }
}
```

I would like to find a way to curse through this list and combine the items so that they are organized in a propper hiereachy such that all counties in Texas fall under a single Texas set. The same should apply for cities in the same county.

The desired result would be something similar to:

```
newList[0]
{
    Name: Texas
    ItemSet  :
    {
        Name:Tarrant
        ItemSet:
        { 
            Name:Fort Worth
        }
        ItemSet:
        {
            Name: Arlington
        }

    }
    ItemSet  :
    {
        Name:Dallas
        ItemSet:
        { 
            Name:Dallas
        }
        ItemSet:
        {
            Name: Plano
        }

    }
}
newList[1] = 
{
    Name:Washington
    ItemSet:
    {
        Name:King
        ItemSet:
        {
             Name: Seatle
        }
    }
}
```

In other words I would like to create a new list that would only contain two ItemSets(one for each state). The appropriate county and city levels would be populated in these using the appropriate `ItemSet.Add();`

Please Note there could be an infinite amount of levels in this hierarchy. Not just 3 as shown here.

So far here is what I have but I feel like I am moving in the wrong direction:

I am calling each ItemSet in the list a chunk.

```
public static List<ItemSet> CombineChunks(List<ItemSet> chunks)
{
     List<ItemSet> combinedChunks = new List<ItemSet>();
     //do stuff with chunks

     foreach (var chunk in chunks)
     {
         bool add = true;
         if (combinedChunks.Count == 0)
             combinedChunks.Add(chunk);
         else
         {
            foreach (var c in combinedChunks)
            {
               if (c.Name == chunk.Name)
               {
                  add = false;
                  //move on to child
               }

               if (add == true)
               {
                 combinedChunks.Add(chunk);
               }
            }
            return combinedChunks;
        }
```

Comment: First, I'd recommend to actually use an ISet<T> data structure since you'd like to have a set of unique items. Moreover, since you'd like to make sure to have unique items and the ISet<T> only make comparisons for System.Object, you will have to implement a comparer that knows how to check your Item class and make sure to only have unique instances inside your Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned earlier in the comments, I'd really use an ISet data structure such as the HashSet (which I'll be using in the snippet below). I'd recommand to use two classes as Item should not have knowledge of other items. You should have a class to encapsulate the data of an Item and a ItemMerger which would have all your items inside one structure.

```
    public class Location
    {
        public string State { get; set;}
        public string Country { get; set;}
        public string City {get; set;}
   }

   public class LocationComparer : IEqualityComparer<Location>
   {
        public bool Equals(Location x, Location y)
        {
             if(x == null || y == null) 
                 return false; 

             return x.State.Equals(y.State) &&
                    x.Country.Equals(y.Country) && 
                    x.City.Equals(y.City);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Location loc) 
        {
             if(loc == null) 
                 return 0; 

             var value = 0; 
             if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loc.Country))
                value += loc.Country.Length; 

             if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loc.State))
                value += loc.State.Length; 

             if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loc.City))
                 value += loc.City.Length;

             return length * 89;
        }
   } 

   public class LocationMerger 
   {
         private readonly LocationComparer _comparer = new LocationComparer();

         public Dictionary<string, HashSet<Location>> Locations { get; set;} 

         public LocationMerger()
         {
              Locations = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<Location>>() // will use your custom comparer to check for unique Location instances 
         }

         public void AddChunks(string locationIdentifier,  IEnumerable<Location> locs)
         {
               var hashSet = new HashSet<Location>(_comparer);
               foreach(var l in locs)
                   hashSet.Add(l); 

               Locations.Add(locationIdentifier, hashSet);
         }

   }
```

Comment: This is great. I need to rework it so that it can handle my situation a little bit better. My problem is that in the application I do not have a defined hierarchy, rather it is dynamically produced  based on some user input. Thus, it can be any a combination of several different "sets" or groupings at various levels.

Comment: @LCaraway, please refer to my new updated code with the Dictionary to handle the hierarchy a user would use for a given location

Comment: I am really intrigued by this. Thank you for your help so far. What would you pass in to location Identifier?

Comment: I'd use the same thing that you've shown in your snippet such as "Texas". Glad to be of help! If this helps you, could you accept it :)